# sorting multidimensional array by two values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [arr1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (                   
                    [m] => name1
                    [p] => 261.15
                    [f] => 0.30112588
                )

            [1] => Array
                (                
                    [m] => name2
                    [p] => 214.92
                    [f] => 0.35793662
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [m] => name3
                    [p] => 504.35
                    [f] => 0.35779595
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [m] => name3
                    [p] => 504.35
                    [f] => 0.31910875
                )

            [4] => Array
               (
                    [m] => name3
                    [p] => 504.35
                    [f] => 0.38972548
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [m] => name4
                    [p] => 5500
                    [f] => 0.50674623
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [m] => name5
                    [p] => 600.5
                    [f] => 0.11483321
                )
        )
)
```

I want to sort this array so item with higest ['p'] is on top , but i also want if some items have same ['m'] and same ['p'] than an item with lowest ['f'] is on top of these with same ['m'] and ['p'].

I managed to sort this array by ['p'] using usort function , but i cant sort it by ['f'] only if they have same ['m'] and ['p'].

Code:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['arr1'] = array();

array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name1', 'p' => 261.15 ,'f' => 0.30112588]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name2', 'p' => 214.92 ,'f' => 0.35793662]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name3', 'p' => 504.35 ,'f' => 0.35779595]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name3', 'p' => 504.35 ,'f' => 0.31910875]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name3', 'p' => 504.35 ,'f' => 0.38972548]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name4', 'p' => 5500 ,'f' => 0.50674623]);
array_push($arr['arr1'], ['m' => 'name5', 'p' => 600.5 ,'f' => 0.11483321]);
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Could you please post your code, preferably with the array? It will give us an easy starting point to answer your question. Now all we have is an output of your array.

Comment: Use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php) - take a look at users "cagret" and "jimpoz"'s examples in the bottom of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `usort` function:

condition list:

- sort this array so item with higest `['p']` is on **top**
- the item with lowest `['f']` is on **top** among the items with same `['m']` and `['p']`.

---

```
// $arr is your array
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    if ($a['m'] == $b['m'] && $a['p'] == $b['p']) {
        return ($a['f'] > $b['f'])? 1 : -1;
    }
    return ($b['p'] > $a['p'])? 1 : -1;
});

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [m] => name4
            [p] => 5500
            [f] => 0.50674623
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [m] => name3
            [p] => 504.35
            [f] => 0.31910875
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [m] => name3
            [p] => 504.35
            [f] => 0.35779595
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [m] => name3
            [p] => 504.35
            [f] => 0.38972548
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [m] => name5
            [p] => 500.5
            [f] => 0.11483321
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [m] => name1
            [p] => 261.15
            [f] => 0.30112588
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [m] => name2
            [p] => 214.92
            [f] => 0.35793662
        )
)
```

Comment: Ok. I think u have to replace $arr with $arr['arr1'] in usrot function . Otherwise it look fine. I ll try it.